# I am having trouble installing Ubuntu on my old Dell XPS L321x

Tags: boot, grub2, dell

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on my old Dell XPS L321x. Ubuntu 22.04 fails to boot from either of my USB thumb drive's. I tried Etcher without luck. I can get Ubuntu to boot using Rufus but after installation I get a message "no operation system found" Not sure what is going wrong. I suspect Ubuntu wants to install for UEFI but the laptop uses a legacy bios. I am able to install other distributions without problem.

Comment: No, it has UEFI. However, because it was shipped originally with Windows 7 its (UEFI) firmware was set to Legacy ("BIOS") mode. Before anything else make sure the firmware is updated to the last version published. Then do the exact opposite of you conjecture: Disable CSM/Legacy to assure it boots and installs in UEFI mode. After installing confirm Ubuntu is select as the first boot entry in UEFI settings > Boot and if not change it accordingly.

Comment: I have an L321x and it is not UEFI.  Latest BIOS (A04) does not have any options to enable/disable legacy mode, and no mention of UEFI, boot entries, etc.  The only boot options it has is the boot device order.

Comment: which other distros are you able to install them on the dell xps l321x?

Answer (score 3):

Try installing 18.04 and then update to 20.04 and then update to 22.04.

To upgrade from 18.04 to 22.04, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade    
sudo do-release-upgrade
sudo apt update    
sudo apt dist-upgrade    
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

If all is well with no errors, run the following command:

```
sudo apt  --purge autoremove
```

To upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04, run the same commands.

Comment: That seems to be the best, maybe the only solution. Old versions of Ubuntu work totally fine on this laptop. I have no idea why recent versions of Ubuntu have trouble. Is it missing a specific package that old versions have? Is it the installer? I don't get it. I did more tinkering to no success.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like we can't install the latest Ubuntu releases on legacy non-UEFI hardware.

I used the legacy netboot installer which you can get from here: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/mini.iso

"Focal" seems to be the last release that provides the netboot installer, which isn't too bad.  You can then "do-release-upgrade" once you have installed it to get to the latest release.

I have just done all this on my 2012 Dell XPS L321x including upgrading to 22.04 and so far everything appears to be working fine.